# Looking for workaround for 32 cpu limitation using GetProcessAffinityMask in 32 bit process

Tags: winapi

I've just realized that `GetProcessAffinityMask` can't return values larger than 4'294'967'295 (1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111) in 32 bit applications, even on a 64 bit system.

This means that I'm unable to correctly detect system affinity mask on machines with more than 32 logical processors. Is there any hack to get other half of the affinity mask in this case?

Comment: Even in a 64 bit process (that being the obvious way to try to solve the problem) you come unstuck when there are more than 64 processors. What do you propose to do then?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, wouldn't `SetThreadGroupAffinity()` solve that problem? ;)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
Max cpu group size in windows is 64 so if you have more logical cpus then OS will create "fake" numa nodes.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/processor-groups) might by interesting.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I was wondering whether you were aware of the issue. If you have a multi group process then `GetProcessAffinityMask` returns zero for both masks. I suppose my real point is that `GetProcessAffinityMask` becomes much less useful on such machines because of these issues. So perhaps even if you can succeed in getting the info (e.g. via a 64 bit process) then it may not do you any real good. When I need this information, I call `GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , I just need full affinity mask for current CPU group/NUMA NODE. Do not worry about the rest of things.

Comment: I thought you said you wanted the system affinity mask. The system doesn't have a current CPU group.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , I meant that function GetProcessAffinityMask returns two sets of values lpProcessAffinityMask and lpSystemAffinityMask. 

Example 
GetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(),ProcessAffinityMask,SystemAffinityMask);

Comment: Anyway, the answer is to use 64 bit code

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera `GetProcessAffinityMask()` returns masks as `DWORD_PTR` values, so it can return only 32-bit masks in a 32-bit process, but it can return 64-bit masks in a 64-bit process.

Answer (score 1):

The supported way to do this is to use a 64 bit process.

If you are unable to covert your application to 64 bit then create and call a small helper process to do the work, and pass the information back to your 32 bit application.